# Q-Range - the most mysterious parameter of quantization in Logic Pro X?

Tags: midi, daw, logic-pro

I'm trying to wrap my head around quantization fine-tuning. The one parameter that I doesnt seem to fully understand (for now :P) is Q-Range. I made some research on the web and some people are telling that it's kind of filter:

- positive values quantize only inside the range
- negative values quantize only outside the area

I made a few experiments and I can say that it's not true in 100% situations. Does anybody know how does this parameter really affect the quantized material?

I found this as well ([here's the link](http://www.fransabsil.nl/archpdf/advquant.pdf)), and it seems to be a real thing, but do I really need to spend time analyzing it thoroughly or is there an easier method to understand it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps, but here's what apple says on their [page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH13067?viewlocale=en_CA&locale=en_CA):

```
"Q-Range: Q-Range is ideal for recordings that already have the right
groove but are too hurried or laid back in places. It lets you retain 
the original feel, but positions the rhythmic center precisely in the 
groove. A value of 0 means that every note or transient marker is 
quantized. Negative Q-Range values move only notes or transient markers 
that fall outside the set range to ideal quantization grid positions, 
while those closer to an ideal position are not quantized. In this 
case, the most poorly played notes or transient markers—those outside 
the range—are moved to perfect timing positions on the quantization 
grid (or closer to these positions, depending on the Q-Strength 
setting).

Tip:   To obtain the best Q-Range results, use a low, even Quantize 
value, such as 1/4 note. Set the Q-Range parameter to compensate for 
the maximum error in the recording."
```